# new row with empty spaces added in windows

Tags: python

I have the following code where am writing some data to a .csv file and reading it..data is being written as follows when the script is run on windows,there is a new row with empty spaces being added,when the same script is run on linux there are no empty spaces..can anyone provide inputs on why is it so?

trend.csv

```
6/26/2013   9

6/26/2013   9

6/26/2013   9
```

---

```
import csv
import datetime
from collections import deque
#from collections import maxlength

icount=9
now = datetime.datetime.now()
time =now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
#Keep appending date and count everytime this script is run
c = csv.writer(open("trend.csv", "a"))
c.writerow([time, icount])

with open('trend.csv','rU') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin)
    d=deque(reader,8)
print "Data"
print d
for l in d:
    print l[0]
    print l[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`. `print` add newline.

```
sys.stdout.write(l[0])
sys.stdout.write(l[1])
```

Comment: while writing the data to .csv file itself a new row with emtpy cells being written...print is happening while reading..so am not sure above will solve

Comment: @user2341103, Open csv file with binary mode( `open("trend.csv", "ab")` ).

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to always trim your input rows after reading them in, because Python on different OSes interpret newline characters differently.

Comment: how to trim...while writing the data to .csv file itself a new row with emtpy cells being written.